# reading ip address from json file and placing it as a tag in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, html

I need to read IP address from a json file and place is as a div tag 'data-ip'.
Here is the code:

```
<div id="myid" data-ip="127.1.1.0"><input field 1 />.<input field 2 />.<input field 3 />.<input field 4 /></div>
```

if there is no data to be read in JSON file then data-ip="" will show empty and one can enter valid ip address.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your json to be as `{"ip":"172.10.0.1"}` shown below , you can access its value as `data.ip` and append this value to the `div#myd` using jQuery **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

```js
var ipData = {"ip":"172.10.0.1"};

$('#myid').attr('data-ip', ipData.ip || "");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myid" data-ip="127.1.1.0"><input field 1 />.<input field 2 />.<input field 3 />.<input field 4 /></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton suzo.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help :)